# Sending and receiving a file to an aspx script

Tags: asp.net, ajax, http, file-upload

I have a need to send a file to an aspx script so that it can be processed and then returned.

We have 2 servers (let's call them A and B) and I have a website on server A that allows users to upload a video. When they upload the video I need to pass the file to a script on Server B because I have some software on server B that can process and shrink the video. The script then needs to pass the finished file back to the requesting page on server A so that it can store the processed file and show the user a preview/thumbnail of the video they have just uploaded.

Now, I have the uploading sorted and the video processing script is all in place, I just need to know how to pass the files back and forth without resorting to something slow like FTP. I would guess that it would involve an http request, initiated by a handler called via ajax, but I'm at the limit of my knowledge here (well, beyond the limit really).

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: I presume the servers can't access each other via network shares?

Comment: Please describe your network topology.

Comment: If FTP is slow, an HTTP request would also be slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually solved this by using an ashx handler on server B which I called using a normal httpRequest, no ajax involved, from server A.